# MySQL, remove duplicate lines (must be unique by 2 columns)

Tags: php, mysql

I have this:

```
1899, 184, 531 *
1900, 184, 531 *
1901, 113, 531
1902, 184, 436
```

I want to get

```
1899, 184, 531
1901, 113, 531
1902, 184, 436
```

without temp tables, etc. How to?

Comment: provide `SQL` query that you are using

Comment: Why id 1899 and not 1900 for first record?

Comment: You want to do a SELECT or a DELETE?

Comment: DELETE. I want to have the table with no multiple records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do a SELECT where you filter out the duplicates, you can use this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Col2, Col3 FROM table_name ORDER BY Id;
```

[SQL fiddle for SELECT](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d82ff17/3)

Or if you want a DELETE query, you can do this:

```
DELETE t1 FROM table_name t1, table_name t2
WHERE t1.Id < t2.Id
AND t1.Col2 = t2.Col2 
AND t1.Col3 = t2.Col3;
```

[SQL fiddle for DELETE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9dfe7/1)

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT MIN(Col1), Col2, Col3
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Col2, Col3
```

This assumes that you chose the `1899` record over the `1900` one because the former is the smaller of the two.

If you want to *delete* the duplicate records, as you have defined them as duplicates, from your table, then you can use the following query:

```
DELETE t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT MIN(Col1) AS Col1, Col2, Col3
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY Col2, Col3
) t2
    ON t1.Col1 = t2.Col1 AND t1.Col2 = t2.Col2 AND t1.Col3 = t2.Col3
WHERE t2.Col1 IS NULL
```

Comment: Does he want select `MIN` value for print?

Answer (score 1):

```
select min(f1) as f1, f2, f3 from tbl group by f2, f3
```

Answer (score 1):

For a DELETE:

```
DELETE
FROM table1 t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT u.*
              FROM table1 u
              WHERE u.col2 = t.col2 AND u.col3 = t.col3
              AND u.col1 > t.col1)
```

There of course is the problem of deleting on the same table as the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

For `DELETE`:

```
DELETE t1
FROM yourtable t1
JOIN yourtable t2
ON t1.col2 = t2.col2
AND t1.col3 = t2.col3
AND t1.col1 > t2.col1
```

### SQLFiddle Demo

Answer (score 0):

This can delete duplicate row.

delete from table_name where column1 in(select column1 from (select column1 from table_name group by column1,column2 having count(*)>1) t);